# How to use ISymbol QueryBoundary

Tags: arcgis-engine

I have a balloon callout ISymbol and I want to get a polygon object so I can see if the user clicks it.

I am trying to use the function QueryBoundary
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w00000372000000

The function has four arguments:

```
public void QueryBoundary (
    int hDC,
    ITransformation displayTransform,
    IGeometry Geometry,  //what can I put in here?
    IPolygon boundary
);
```

One of my major hangups with the third argument is simply the fact that I am using this function to try to get the geometry... so what sense does it make to pass in the thing that I want?  Also since the function is called like this :

```
thissymbol.QueryBoundary(screenDisplay.hDC, displayTransformation, thisGeometry, polygon);
```

Presumably it doesn't need the geometry of "thissymbol" since "thissymbol" is the caller.

Answer (score 4):

That would depend on the type of symbol.  For a point symbol, I would cast displayTransformation.VisibleBounds to IArea, then pass IArea.Centroid as the geometry.

For line symbols you need a polyline.  For fill symbols I think either a polygon or an envelope will work.